# Convert a sequence to hashMap in clojure

Tags: clojure, sequence

I am very new to clojure and I am reading a csv and getting a sequence as follows-

```
[[1501493_raw_html.txt 0] 
 [1501553_raw_html.txt 0]
 [1501589_raw_html.txt 0]
 [1501685_raw_html.txt 0]
 [1501727_raw_html.txt 0]]
```

I want to convert the same to a map of key value as follows-

```
[
{:key 1501493_raw_html.txt :value 0}
{:key 1501553_raw_html.txt :value 0}
{:key 1501589_raw_html.txt :value 0}
...
]
```

I tried -

```
(def record (interleave [:key :value] (rest read-csv)))

(def arrange-csv-map
  ;(zipmap [:key :value] read-csv)
  (apply hash-map record)
  )

(println "Read-csv " (first arrange-csv-map ))
```

which is returning output as-

```
Read-csv  [:key [119_raw_html.txt 0]]
```

I tried few other ways like

```
(into {} [:key (first value) :value {rest value}])
```

but nothing worked as I expected.

Comment: You are not converting a sequence to a map. You are converting a *vector of vectors* to a *vector of maps* - where a vector is a kind of sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your commented out `zipmap` was on the right track (`interleave` could work but `zipmap` is simpler). Both of your attempts most likely failed because you were working on `read-csv` which, I assumes, in your context is a collection or sequence of lines and not on a single line at a time.

`(zipmap [:key :value] a-line)` does the transformation you want for one line. Now you have to do that for all lines, with `map`:

```
(map (fn [line] (zipmap [:key :value] line)) read-csv)
```

Comment: Perhaps ```mapv``` as he wanted a vector collection as output

Comment: @FrankC. These days (Clojure 1.7+) I prefer `(into [] (map f) coll)` to `(mapv f coll)`.

Comment: @cgrand why should I use into , is there any performance implication ?

Comment: @FrankC. To me `mapv` (and `filterv`) are legacy: their usecases are better served by `(into [] xform coll)` which is more generic (works with any transducer not just `map` and `filter`).

Comment: @cgrand - Cool, I was wondering what was driving your comment.

Answer (score 2):

ABC

Clojure's [reduce](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) will do the trick for you:

```
(def sample [[1501493_raw_html.txt 0] 
 [1501553_raw_html.txt 0]
 [1501589_raw_html.txt 0]
 [1501685_raw_html.txt 0]
 [1501727_raw_html.txt 0]])

(reduce #(conj %1 (assoc {} 
           :key (get %2 0)
           :value (get %2 1))) [] sample)
```

This is basically saying "For each vector, convert positional elements to respective keys in a new map and accumulate in another vector"

Answer (score 1):

I think using `for` is even simpler in this case, and makes the conversion of each element in to a map more obvious:

```
(ns ...
  (:require [clojure.pprint :refer [pprint] ] ...

(def data-list 
  [ ["1501493_raw_html.txt" 0] 
    ["1501553_raw_html.txt" 0]
    ["1501589_raw_html.txt" 0]
    ["1501685_raw_html.txt" 0]
    ["1501727_raw_html.txt" 0] ] )

(def result
  (for [entry data-list]
    { :key    (entry 0)
      :value  (entry 1) } ))
(pprint result)
```

Which gives the result:

```
> lein run
({:key "1501493_raw_html.txt", :value 0}
 {:key "1501553_raw_html.txt", :value 0}
 {:key "1501589_raw_html.txt", :value 0}
 {:key "1501685_raw_html.txt", :value 0}
 {:key "1501727_raw_html.txt", :value 0})
```

Comment: Better still if you destructure entry rather than calling it with 1 and 0, which seems rather awkward to me: `(for [[k v] data-list] {:key k :value v})`